# Como dar count até um valor limitado, "countar até 90 em uma tabela que tem 100"

Tags: sql, query, count, informix

Montei a seguinte Query - "INFORMIX"

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT * FROM NOTA_FISCAL_NFE LIMIT 90);
```

Que me retorna o seguinte erro:

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command: SELECT COUNT(1) FROM
>   (SELECT * FROM NOTA_FISCAL_NFE LIMIT 90);
>
> A syntax error has occurred. [SQL State=42000, DB Errorcode=-201] 1
>   statement failed.
>
> Execution time: 0.02s

**Quero realizar um count em uma tabela até um valor especifico, mesmo que tenha mais registros, só quero saber se possui aquela quantidade especifica, no exemplo "90".**

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NOTA_FISCAL_NFE LIMIT 90;`

Comment: O código que você postou na pergunta não corresponde ao código executado no SGBD segundo a mensagem de erro: `SELECT TABLE_TESTE.COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT * FROM NOTA_FISCAL_NFE LIMIT 90) AS TABLE_TESTE`. No caso do código na mensagem de erro, vocÊ informou `TABELA_TESTE.COUNT(1)`, que realmente está errado. Se você escrever como perguntou deveria funcionar, apesar de a subquery ser desnecessária.

Comment: Então, pior que não funciona, más atualizei o erro agora.

Comment: Em termos de logica, seu SQL não tem muito sentido. Faz sentido apenas por uma questão de limitação técnica/performance. Mas no Informix não tem problemas de performance quando executado `count(*)` , como ocorre com o Oracle ou Sql Server. Todos os count(*) são retornados instantaneamente porque o Informix mantem um controle online da quantidade de linhas de todas as tabelas. Pode fazer o count simples sem medo que vai ser rápido: `select count(*) from nota_fiscal_nfe;`

Answer (score -1):

Seria bom você especificar o banco de dados que está trabalhando.
Geralmente você precisa especificar um alias quando faz uma subquery.
Outra coisa, substitua o '1' por um '*' ou pelo nome de uma coluna.

```
select count(*) 
from (
    select * from NOTA_FISCAL_NFE limit 90
) as tabela_subquery;
```

Comment: Essa `sub-query` não é necessária.

Comment: Não funcionou cara.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos Sem essa sub-query, o resultado poderá ser superior a 90. Pelo que entendi, isso não pode ocorrer.

Comment: @FrancoPan o resultado será o mesmo com ou sem a `sub-query`.

Comment: Importante: O Informix suporta a sintaxe do `limit` igua do MySQL apenas nas versões mais recentes. Mas não suporta o uso dele dentro de subqueries, quando especificado no fim do SQL, mas se for especificado no começo, funciona : `select limit 90 ...`

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.